# get exact value of elements from json body

Tags: python, json, extract, spyder

I am looking to extract specific values from json objects. Please see the json body below.

**json**

```
 data.json = [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "modifiedBy": "admin",
      "fields": {
        "Application": "1",
        "Endtermin": 23011990
        }
      },
      {
      "id": 2,
      "modifiedBy": "admin",
      "fields": {
        "Application": "2",
        "Endtermin": 11021990
        }
      }
      ]
```

I want to print only 'Application' from the list in a table form where table consists of one row and two columns.

Application = 1, 2

I tried in python, but getting error. 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

**Python**

```
 import json
 import sys
 data = [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "modifiedBy": "admin",
      "fields": {
        "Application": "1",
        "Endtermin": 23011990
        }
      },
      {
      "id": 2,
      "modifiedBy": "admin",
      "fields": {
        "Application": "2",
        "Endtermin": 11021990
        }
      }
      ]

 json_str = json.dumps(data)

 resp = json.loads(json_str)

 print (resp)

 print (resp['Application'])
```

Comment: Please iterate through each element and of data list and access the required value using element["fields"]["Application"].
Also, there is no need to dump and load back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, `data` is already a dictionary object, you don't need `json` and can simply use list comprehension as:

```
apps = [elt["fields"]["Application"] for elt in data] # Output ['1', '2']
```

You could also use `get()` in case the `keys` are missing for some elements in the list:

```
apps = [elt.get("fields",{}).get("Application") for elt in data] # Output ['1', '2']
```

Comment: Oh that was really easy. Thank you.